# Transpose matrices in Java

Tags: java, matrix, transpose

I think I'm missing something small but I can't tell what it might be. I'm trying to create a method that will transpose a matrix. For example, if I input a 2x3 matrix, it'll output a 3x2 matrix.

If I input {1, 1, 1}
{1, 1, 1}

I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException

It's telling me that my error occurs on the line that "says newTranspose.data[j][i] = data[i][j];" but I don't know what else to do. I've tried swapping i's and j's and numRows/numColumns for data.length but I'm stuck at this point.

Above this method, I have instance variables 'private in numRows' and 'private int numColumns' to set the dimensions of the matrix. I have another instance variable 'private int data[][]' that's the internal storage of the matrix elements. Then I have a Constructor for a new Matrix that automatically determines dimensions.

```
   public Matrix(int d[][]) {
        // d.length is the number of 1D arrays in the 2D array
        numRows = d.length;
        if (numRows == 0)
            numColumns = 0;
        else
            numColumns = d[0].length; // d[0] is the first 1D array

        // create a new matrix to hold the data
        data = new int[numRows][numColumns];

        // copy the data over
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++)
                data[i][j] = d[i][j];
    }

   public Matrix transpose() {
        Matrix newTranspose = new Matrix(data);

        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++)
                newTranspose.data[j][i] = data[i][j];

        return newTranspose;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the constructor.

Comment: To fix this you need to make sure the length of the matrix to transpose can accommodate the row to column switch. Your indexes will go out of bounds if j<i and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this statement:  `Matrix newTranspose = new Matrix(data)`

One effect of that statement will be that `newTranspose` will have the same contents, but more importantly, the same number of rows and same number of columns as the original matrix.  The nested loops are sure to throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` whenever the source array is not square.

One way to fix it is to declare a new 2D array:

```
  public Matrix transpose () {
     int [][] hold = new int [numColumns] [numRows];
     for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++)
           hold [j][i] = data[i][j];
  return new Matrix (hold); 
}
```